# java bufferedreader, declaration readline

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, java-io

I am implementing a Socket, which it will accept data from a server. The server will send data record, which will be separated by the stx,data,etx. My question is, if I use the following code:

```
client = new Socket("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 50000);
BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

 String line;
 while ((line = d.readLine()) != null) {
     // do something
 }
```

It will automatically do the seperation of each data record? Or I have to do it by myself? Thanks

STX = Start Of Text (ASCII character)

ETX = End Of Text (ASCII character)

Comment: maybe i'm not fully understanding but.. what is "data record" and what do you mean by "separated by the stx, data, etx."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the Javadoc for BufferedReader.readLine()

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So you can see it doesn't do anything like what you want.

> Or I have to do it by myself?

I suggest you either use Scanner with a custom delimiter or you parse the BufferedReader one character at a time.

Comment: You are right! My fault. My head is like mixer now. I will consider your answer. Thanks @Peter Lawrey.